# AngularJS - Repeater item updating a parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a question that contains 4 answers.  The answers are in a repeater with an ng-click binding that sets the answer to answered=true, but I also want to set the parent question to answered = true as well.

```
$scope.questions = [{
    "text": "1111What do you think of this asdf asdf asdf asdf sdf asdf as?",
    "answers":[
        {text:"answer 1", answered:false},
        {text:"answer 2", answered:false},
        {text:"answer 3", answered:false},
        {text:"answer 4", answered:false}],
    "answered": false
},{
    "text": "22What do you think of this asdf asdf asdf asdf sdf asdf as?",
    "answers":[
        {text:"answer 21", answered:false},
        {text:"answer 22", answered:false},
        {text:"answer 23", answered:false},
        {text:"answer 24", answered:false}],
    "answered": false
}];
$scope.registerAnswer = function(){
   if (this.answer) {
       this.answer.answered = true;
       this.answer.$parent.$parent.answered = true;
   }
};

// html::
<button ng-click=registerAnswer()></button>
```

How can I get a child to update it's parent?

http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/VnQqH/197/

http://plnkr.co/edit/KVjA64JaopofX5KuKXPr

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to make it much more complex than it should be. Just use

```
ng-click="registerAnswer(answer, question)"
```

and define the registerAnswer function as

```
$scope.registerAnswer = function(answer, question) {
    answer.answered = true;
    question.answered = true;
}
```